# java file writing within shared folder

Tags: java

How to write excel sheets in the shared network folder using Java API.I think before writing the files ,first program should authenticate it.

Please provide any hints.

Comment: have you at least google this? http://www.google.com/search?q=excel+java. It's on the first page!!!

Comment: @chahuistle: I know how to write data into excel,but i want the code for authentication to network folder before writing into it.

Comment: uhm... what about running your java program under a user that has permissions to the desired files?

Comment: No,one more thing is program running in unix machine and i have to write files in windows machine :)

Comment: what about giving permissions to that unix user accessing the files? or using ftp? or perhaps share that folder using samba?

Comment: What protocol is being used to share the resource?

Comment: @Patrick: Not sure but i think it should be ftp only right.

Comment: chahuistle: Suppose if user has access,how to authenticate that folder first and if succes using java api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) library to access a Windows [SMB](http://www.samba.org/cifs/docs/what-is-smb.html) share in Java.  Using it, you could do something like the following:

```
String smbUrl = "smb://username:password@server/share/file";
SmbFileOutputStream fos = new SmbFileOutputStream(new SmbFile(smbURL));
```

Errors will result in an SmbException.

If you really did want FTP, look at the [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) library.  There are a ton of examples all over the place for that one.

Answer (score -2):

First link on Google: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

Please learn how to Google :)